# gluing together continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

HI I was checking and old question here and I have troubles to proof the following:

**Proposition**: Let $X$ be a space with subspaces $Y,A,B$ such that $X \backslash Y= A \sqcup B$ (disjoint union). Let $g: X \to Z$ be a function such that $g$ is continous when restricted to each of $Y \cup A, Y \cup B$. Then $g$ is continuous.

Let $f_1= g \mid Y \cup A $ and similarly $f_2= g\mid Y\cup B$. Let $U$ open in $Z$ then

$$g^{-1}(U)= (g^{-1}(U)\cap(Y \cup A))\cup (g^{-1}(U)\cap (Y \cup B))\\
=f_1^{-1}(U)\cup f_2^{-1}(U)$$

and $f_1^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y\cup A$ but how do we know that is also open in $X$? There is another approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is not true as stated.

For a counterexample we can take $X=\mathbb R$, $Y=\varnothing$, $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, and
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x\in A \\ 0 & x \in B \end{cases} $$
Then $g$ is continuous (indeed constant) on each of $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$, but *everywhere discontinuous* on $X$.

The claim does become true if we assume, for example, that $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$.

Comment: The problem as stated is that $Y$ is connected and $A,B$ are mutually separated.

Comment: @JoseAntonio: I don't see any such statement in your question. You should probably ask a new question that includes your previously secret assumptions.

Comment: I take it from  here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90746/if-y-is-connected-why-is-a-cup-y-connected-in-this-case the answer of Ronnie Brown, but as you mentioned the proposition as stated is not correct. But anyway using the assumption of the general problem I have troubles to show that are open in the general topological space